# Django detailview in bootstrap modal

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal, detailview

How i can get detail view in bootstrap5 modal? (Without jquery please).

Modal opens from link(no from button).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your information I imagine some kind of object list and you want details per object in a bootstrap modal. That's not a DetailView but a ListView and should just work out of the box. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview